# Can I find usages of this string in my .so file? ARM

Tags: android, ghidra

My apologies if this question is very basic. I have found this string in my Android application Binary that was built using the flutter framework. This is a 32 bit ARM library. I found the location of a url string at "00c88fa0" located below. I want to find the assembly code that loads and uses this string. I used Ghidra's "show call trees" and "Show references to address" functionality, but they have been unable to help me. I assume the string is being referenced by a base address + offset calculation. Is there an easy way for me to find this section of the code? Or is it not easily possible because there are too many base + offset calculations that could arrive at my String?

Thank you.

[image: M]

Updated image:

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure the whole .text section has been disassembled?  If not the xref would not have been created.

Comment: I did another run of the autoanalyzer changing a few settings. I think it has disassembled more of the text section and added functions to the symbol tree. However, I don't see any xref links to this string. I am sure this string is used as well.

Comment: Have you looked a little _before_ the actual string? Suppose it is a counted string, you'd expect something like "maximum" and "current length" before the string (or, if there is no flat version of the counted strings, such record could _point to_ the string you have identified).

Comment: I edited my post with more bytes. Actually a bit of background what I am doing is that this url was originally a https url. As part of a pen test I am conducting I wanted to intercept the traffic and needed to downgrade the connection to http instead of https. In the past I achieved this by removing the "s" in the url and padding the end of the string with a null byte thinking that it would terminate 1 byte early. This time the null byte gets added to the url. So long story short I do believe that this is a counted string. I wanted to find the counting code so that I could fix it and learn.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there were many servers not automatically redirecting http->https these days... it would be quicker to check for redirection in a browser first rather than modify the app.

Answer (score 1):

In Ghidra, it is possible to view the references to a given address in memory as shown in the picture:
[image: How to see references to a string in memory]